# How to get Network Strength in Android Application?

Tags: android

I want to show a network strength of internet in mobile device.

now I am able to check connection from wifi or not using code below, But further I need network Signal Strength. so please tell me what code I need to add?

Thanks!

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);



        TextView netStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.netStatus);
        if (activeNetInfo != null) {
            netStatus.setText(" Connection Status - Connected "+activeNetInfo.getTypeName());
        } else if (mobNetInfo != null) {
            netStatus.setText(" Connection Status - Connected "+mobNetInfo.getTypeName());
        } else {
            netStatus.setText(" Connection Status - Not Connected ");
        }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#calculateSignalLevel%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code :

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
    } else {
        int netType = Info.getType();
        int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

        if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            List<ScanResult> scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            for (int i = 0; i < scanResult.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("scanResult", "Speed of wifi"+scanResult.get(i).level);//The db level of signal 
            }


            // Need to get wifi strength
        } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection");
            // Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your effort, But what about TYPE_MOBILE as this code gives only -1 when net provider is sim card.

Comment: This may help :-http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

Comment: how can i get speed in kbps using this signal level

Comment: How can we find the network speed if we are using 3G instead of WIFI?

Answer (score 4):

```
    public class Connectivity {
        /*
         * These constants aren't yet available in my API level (7), but I need to
         * handle these cases if they come up, on newer versions
         */
        public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD = 14; // Level 11
        public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B = 12; // Level 9
        public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP = 15; // Level 13
        public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN = 11; // Level 8
        public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_LTE = 13; // Level 11

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * 
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is fast connectivity
     * 
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static String isConnectedFast(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if ((info != null && info.isConnected())) {
            return Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),
                    info.getSubtype());
        } else
            return "No NetWork Access";

    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * 
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return
     */
    public static String isConnectionFast(int type, int subType) {
        if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            System.out.println("CONNECTED VIA WIFI");
            return "CONNECTED VIA WIFI";
        } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            switch (subType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return "NETWORK TYPE 1xRTT"; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return "NETWORK TYPE CDMA (3G) Speed: 2 Mbps"; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:

                return "NETWORK TYPE EDGE (2.75G) Speed: 100-120 Kbps"; // ~
                                                                        // 50-100
                                                                        // kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return "NETWORK TYPE EVDO_0"; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return "NETWORK TYPE EVDO_A"; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return "NETWORK TYPE GPRS (2.5G) Speed: 40-50 Kbps"; // ~ 100
                                                                        // kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return "NETWORK TYPE HSDPA (4G) Speed: 2-14 Mbps"; // ~ 2-14
                                                                    // Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return "NETWORK TYPE HSPA (4G) Speed: 0.7-1.7 Mbps"; // ~
                                                                        // 700-1700
                                                                        // kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return "NETWORK TYPE HSUPA (3G) Speed: 1-23 Mbps"; // ~ 1-23
                                                                    // Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return "NETWORK TYPE UMTS (3G) Speed: 0.4-7 Mbps"; // ~ 400-7000
                                                                    // kbps
                // NOT AVAILABLE YET IN API LEVEL 7
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
                return "NETWORK TYPE EHRPD"; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
                return "NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B"; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "NETWORK TYPE HSPA+ (4G) Speed: 10-20 Mbps"; // ~ 10-20
                                                                    // Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "NETWORK TYPE IDEN"; // ~25 kbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "NETWORK TYPE LTE (4G) Speed: 10+ Mbps"; // ~ 10+ Mbps
                // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                return "NETWORK TYPE UNKNOWN";
            default:
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this showing network signal strength. It just shows the possible network bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

to get the `Network Strength`

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
netStatus.setText(getWifiSignalStrengthIndBm()+"");

public int getWifiSignalStrengthIndBm() {
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    return asu2dBm(wifiInfo.getRssi());
}
private int asu2dBm(int asu) {
        return (2 * asu) - 113;
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of subtracting 113? I get -201% signal strength from this code

Comment: As far as I can see (without running this code) he is talking about dBm and not %.